# FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true); does not shrink window iframe, how to setAutoShrink so it works both ways

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is a really annoying problem I keep having with facebook page tabs.

I use `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);` to automatically resize the iframe to the content, which works great, but only one way. Works nice when the page grows from jQuery animation and ajax objects.

But `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);` only seems to work when it grows, not if I navigate to a page within my page iframe that is shorter than previous page.

I get a big white block appear at the bottom, which is the height of my previous page.

How can I shrink the facebook iframe when a page gets smaller? Any help would be great thanks.

This is how i'm currently using the auto grow...

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({
        appId      : '<?php global $app_id; echo $app_id; ?>', // App ID
        channelUrl : '<?php global $channel_url; echo $channel_url; ?>',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);

};
```

Comment: You can only shrink the iframe height by using `FB.Canvas.setSize`, and explicitly giving the height yourself.

Comment: Yes - I think the function is named setAutoGrow because it only grows

Answer (score 1):

this would help

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({"appId": "624452304314106", "status": true, "cookie": true, "xfbml": true});
  //FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
  //FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0); 
    FB.Canvas.setSize({height:600});
    setTimeout("FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()",500);
};
```

reference: http://www.twistermc.com/36764/shrink-facebook-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Use FB.Canvas.scrollTo to scroll to top.

```
FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/